# Converting DOCX to PDF in batch on Mac using docx2pdf

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to convert folders containing docx to pdfs using docx2pdf.I've been following the guidance I found for this package and some questions on Stackoverflow but don't seem to be able to overcome the following issue (still very new to all this and even newer to working on a Mac).

Working from the Terminal I enter `/usr/bin/env python` to be able to run my code.

```
from docx2pdf import convert
convert("path-to-folder/")
```

[output of my code: 0it [00:05, ?it/s]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0fXg.png)

For some folders instead of 00:05 it says 00:00 - I don't get any additional information and am a bit confused as to what is going on.(The files are not converted) Could someone help me understand what the output means? My understanding is that the 00:00 indicates the time elapsed but I'm unsure how to interpret it in terms of converting the documents.

In previous attempts it did not come up with this output but opened Word and asked for permission but now that I get his output, this does not happen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem, turns out the path I was giving didnt contain any .docx files. Changing the path fixed it.